# facebook graph api vs fql ? which is faster?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am attempting to develop a facebook application . I came across facebook graph api and fql  to fetch data from facebbok. As per my application i need to fetch lots of information from facebook using either of one .
Can anyone suggest which is more faster graph api or fql interm for fetching heavy data ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph api has its mertis and demerits , so does the fql.

Graph api is simple, easy to use and more structured (atleast for me), but fql is more powerful than graph api.

There are some queries which you cannot do in graph api or atleast you will need multiple calls from graph api but just a single call via fql.

**In a nutshell,


There are operations which only fql can do (and graph api fails) but there is no operation which graph api can do and fql cannot :)**

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. FQL is better if you want to get data that a Graph API call doesn't directly provide. For example, if you want to get information from multiple tables. In terms of speed, it really depends on how complex the FQL query is and how much data is retrieved from Facebook.

Simple calls will be quicker via the Graph API and must easer to call instead of the FQL equivalent. But, FQL is more powerful as already mentioned.